# Pointing a sub domain to another server using Directi control panel while domain is not hosted

Tags: domains, redirects, dns, subdomain

Do we always need a host for `domain.com`? Unfortunately currently the host for `example.com` is down, so `sub.example.com` cannot be redirected to where it should.

Is there a way to at least activate the `sub.example.com` using DirectI control panel that I have?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  `example.com` and `sub.example.com` are two different names. In the DNS, one can have `A`/`AAAA` records and the other not.

Answer (score 1):

As the issue would be with the server dns or server overload, any subdomain used would still have the same issue. The only way would be to have a ghosted or mirror image of the site to show. You would have sub.domain.com being on a different server using a different set of NS values. Also, you may want to have some sort of caching system in place that could essentially server up the data until such issue is resolved. I've see systems like Cloudflare server up cached data while the system is down.